# Change the height of a video and keep the same width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I have a video And I want to change the height and keep the same width For example width on full screen I Think is 100% and Height Just 200px same to this website  www.paypal.com
The Problem is when I change the height width also change automatically, And video  go to the center(stretched horizontally)

```
        <video autoplay class="embed-responsive-item">
          <source src=test.mp4 type=video/mp4>
        </video>
```

video{ width: 100%; height: 200px; }

Thanks Advance For any help

Comment: The video itself is an element that is fed into a page identical as it already exists.  I'm unaware of a tool that will render your video in a different dimension or aspect ratio and your users probably wouldn't want that either.  In addition anything you're using in bootstrap is going to intentionally keep you from being able to do something like that as the entire point of the "response" embed video is to size to the screen view size by aspect ratio so your video doesn't look horrible.  You'd need to re render the video source externally to the specific view size you're trying to create.

Answer (score 3):

That PayPal website uses the CSS property `object-fit: cover` to fit the video the same width.

> The **object-fit** CSS property specifies how the contents of a replaced element should be fitted to the box established by its used height and width.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

```
.hero-home video {
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: -1;
    object-fit: cover; /* this makes it fit within the video container */
    opacity: 0.9;
    transition: opacity 0.3s ease 0s;
}
```

Possible values for `object-fit`

```
/* Keyword values */
object-fit: fill;
object-fit: contain;
object-fit: cover;
object-fit: none;
object-fit: scale-down;

/* Global values */
object-fit: inherit;
object-fit: initial;
object-fit: unset;
```

They also are using a mix of `max-width`, `min-width`, and `min-height` on the some of the parent elements of the `<video>` element.

Just inspect the CSS to see what their doing. You will see that part of the video is being hidden, not displaying all the height of the video on the `.video-container` using `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir that's what I want,But Please can you help me to make the same but with position: relative , because I want to add some text under this vidéo and with absolute position I met some problems :) Thank you so much!

Comment: When using `position` `absolute`, you have to make sure you also use `position` `relative` on the main video parent element. So your absolutely positioned element is relative to its parent. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position ..

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can give width and height to the container your video is in and then give the video element min-width/height like this the video will stay in the center and only the width will change and not the height.

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
video {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
```